# Linear systems over non-algebraically closed field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-scheme, reference-request

Let $X$ be a regular, irreducible projective scheme, of finite type over an arbitrary field $k$. Both Weil divisors and Cartier divisors are defined on $X$ and naturally correspond. If $k$ is algebraically closed (but of arbitrary characteristic), then we know (Hartshorne, Prop II.7.7) that global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ correspond to effective divisors linearly equivalent to $D$. Is the same thing true for schemes such as $X$ above?

In particular, if $k=\bar{k}$ we can tell that $D$ is not effective if $\dim_k \Gamma (\mathcal{O}_X(D) = 0$. In general, do we at least know that $D$ is linearly equivalent to an effective divisor iff $\dim_k \Gamma (\mathcal{O}_X(D) \ne 0$.

It doesn't seem to be very hard to just repeat Hartshorne's proof to a more general setting, but I would also like to know what the most general versions of this correspondence are. For example, what if $X$ is only proper over $k$, or maybe over something like $\textrm{Spec } \mathbb{Z[1/2]}$. Is essentially the same thing true - or is it actually false? Any references will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dear LMN, I think the answer to all your questions is *yes*.  Everything is true.

See for example, Proposition 2.9 in Hartshorne's *Generalized divisors on Gorenstein schemes* and for some corrections, see Remark 2.9 Hartshorne's *Generalized divisors and biliaison*.

Here's a statement (more general versions can be found in those references).  This version is basically 2.9 in the first reference.

**Theorem:** *if $X$ is a normal Noetherian separated scheme, then for any Weil divisor $D$ on $X$, there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between non-degenerate global sections* $s \in \Gamma(X, O_X(D))$, *modulo sections of* $\Gamma(X, O_X^*)$, *and the set of effective divisors $D' \sim D$.*

Here *non-degenerate* means not being contained in any prime associated to a generic point of any irreducible component of $X$ if I recall correctly.

In particular, I think the reason why Hartshorne generally assumed that $k = \overline{k}$ is that in these cases, these global sections can be used to induce maps to various projective spaces easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been wondering this sort of thing for a while.